# How to solve $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x-1}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

How to solve the following question?

> \begin{eqnarray}
> \\\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)&=&\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x-1}\\
> \\&=&\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}}{x-1}\\
> \\&=&\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{  \frac{\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}}{x}}{\frac{x-1}{x}}\\
> \\&=&\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-1}}{1-\frac{1}{x}}\\
> \\&=&\frac {\sqrt{-1}}{1}\\
> \\&=&\text{Error Math}\\
> \end{eqnarray}

The ans is 0.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It should be $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ instead of $\lim_{x\to0}$.

Comment: $\cos x$ stays between $-1$ and $1$, and $x-1$ gets big.

Comment: @CasperLI : I think your false is that you replace $\frac{sin^2(x)}{x^2}$ with 1 , it applies when $x \to 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $x\rightarrow \infty$ the fraction $\frac{1}{x-1}\rightarrow 0$

Since $|cos(x)|\leq 1$ the limit $\frac{cos(x)}{x-1}\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Since cos(x) is in [-1,1] and the denominator tend to infinity, the result should be 0?

Comment: @Casper Li Exactly!

Answer (score 5):

This can be solved by using the [Sandwich Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

You know that:

$$-1 ≤ \cos x ≤ 1$$

Therefore the function $\frac{\cos x}{x - 1}$ will have the range of:

$$[\frac{-1}{x - 1}, \frac{1}{x-1}]$$

Apply the limit to this range, what do you get?

This is a result of the fact that cos(x) is a bounded function.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you want the first place where your solution goes wrong, it is in this equality that you use: $\cos x = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 x}$. This is simply not true.

On an unrelated note, you don't really need to make any smart substitutions for $\cos x$. To find the limit it is enough to know that $\cos x$ is a bounded function.

Comment: This is indeed the first error, but not the most important one (the extra modulus doesn't change much). The next transition goes really wrong, though.

Comment: $cosx = \sqrt{cos^2x} = \sqrt{1-sin^2x}$ I cannot do that?

Comment: Yes, you cannot. You use the incorrect identity $x = \sqrt{x^2}$. In reality, $|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$.

Comment: No, because $\cos x$ has negative values too, which cannot be reached by a square-root. :)

Comment: Oh~ I see...Thanks

Comment: If $x$ were going to $0$ instead of $\infty$ then you could use this identity, because when $|x|$ is small enough $\cos x$ is positive, and then indeed $\cos x = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 x}$.

Comment: This doesn't mean that the original identity from which you've derived this is incorrect too. $\cos^2x + \sin^2x = 1$ is perfectly applicable.

Comment: @Feanor I agree, I just went for the first one. Both errors have a similar origin: they attempt to use techniques that are used when $x \to 0$ and $\sin x$ is equivalent to $x$.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how you pass from $\sqrt{1-\sin ^2 x}$ to $\sqrt{1/x^2-1}$ (the latter is obviously ill defined for $x \to \infty$. If you are trying to use $\sin x \sim x$, this only holds for *small* $x$.

The limit should be $0$ because $1/(x-1) \to 0$ and $\cos$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

You should not substitute $x$ instead of $\sin x$.